# How to handle data inconsistency with chained updates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I'm building an application using go and mongodb.

Due to my schema design, some informations are stored in multiple places. For example, the relation between a `student` and a `class` object will be stored both in the `student` and in the `class` collection.

That means that if I have to update it, i have to update both collections too, right ? But what if one update fails but not the other ? Is there a way to "cancel all changes on fail" ? Or should i create a daemon program that regularly checks for inconsistent data/relations ?

Comment: You are probably storing student id with the class collection. So, updating student data doesn't affect the student id in the class collection. In case, you are storing some student data within the class collection also, and updating both places, then you need to update both collections in a transaction. Sometimes, such data can be updated only to the student collection immediately _and_ schedule the update of the class collection later - at the end of the day, etc., depending upon the importance of the data and the operation.

Comment: You may want to check out [transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/)